# I am getting "Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)" in codewars

Tags: python, list, append

**Here is the task**
Delta Generators
In mathematics, the symbols Δ and d are often used to denote the difference between two values. Similarly, differentiation takes the ratio of changes (ie. dy/dx) for a linear relationship. This method can be applied multiple times to create multiple 'levels' of rates of change. (A common example is x (position) -> v (velocity) -> a (acceleration)).

Today we will be creating a similar concept. Our function delta will take a sequence of values and a positive integer level, and return a sequence with the 'differences' of the original values. (Differences here means strictly b - a, eg. [1, 3, 2] => [2, -1]) The argument level is the 'level' of difference, for example acceleration is the 2nd 'level' of difference from position. The specific encoding of input and output lists is specified below.

The example below shows three different 'levels' of the same input.

```
input = [1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, 22]
list(delta(input, 1)) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list(delta(input, 2)) # [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
list(delta(input, 3)) # [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

And this is my solution for this problem

```
def delta(values, n):
    lst=[]
    values=list(values).copy()
    for i in range(n):
        lst.clear()
        lst=[0]*(len(values)-1)
        for j in range(1,len(values)):
            #lst.append(values[j]-values[j-1])
            lst[j-1]=values[j]-values[j-1]
            #print(lst)
        values.clear()
        values=lst.copy()
    return values
```

First I used a method `append()` but it was saying "Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)". Then I tried another thing to add the values to a lst and again the same promlem.
Kindly asking for help because I recently started studying programming:)))

Comment: Also my code has to work for endless generators (maybe that is why I am gettimg this error)

Comment: Did you try to run the code on your own computer? Do you understand what the result should be for various inputs? What happens when you try those inputs? How is that different from what you expect? [Did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [look for a cause](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for this problem, for example by carefully checking what the code does when it runs, step by step?

Comment: In your own words, how do you intend for the code to work, step by step? Where you create copies of lists, why? Where you clear list contents, why? Do you know what size of input you are expected to be able to handle?

Comment: "Kindly asking for help because I recently started studying programming:)))" - please read [ask] and note well that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**. Questions here are intended to help build a searchable Q&A library. They **are not** so that we can "help you" or find the bug. We cannot generically offer "help" because that [is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236); and we **are not interested** in your personal level of experience or in offering mentoring - we are here to **answer a question**.

Comment: "Also my code has to work for endless generators (maybe that is why I am gettimg this error)" - please [edit] the question to include this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `values` is of indefinite size, you have to deal with its content incrementally. You can't put it in a list, because you don't have infinite memory, which means you can't use indexing to access the items. Instead, you can do those subtractions one at a time, only keeping track of the two elements you need in order to do that: the current item, and the last one.

Here is how you can do that for "level 1" using a generator. (We'll ignore `n` for now.)

```
def delta(values, n):
    values = iter(values)
    a = next(values)
    for b in values:
        yield b - a
        a = b
```

One thing that may trip you up here is the use of `iter()`. If the argument to `iter()` is a container, `iter()` returns an iterator over the container. If it's already an iterator, `iter()` returns the same iterator.  So in this case, it's a way to let our function accept either lists or iterators, because it needs to do that.

Once we for sure have an iterator, we use `next()` to get the first value from it. That way we have an initial value to subtract from the second value. The loop actually loops over the second through last values since we already got the first value with `next()`.

Now to add the levels, the most straightforward way is probably to use recursion. For values of `n` greater than 1, instead of iterating over the items in `values` directly, you iterate over the items from the next lower level instead.  When `n` is 1, you iterate directly over `values`.

And that looks like this:

```
def delta(values, n):
    if n > 1:
        values = delta(values, n-1)
    values = iter(values)
    a = next(values)
    for b in values:
        yield b - a
        a = b
```

You can make it a bit shorter by using a conditional expression:

```
def delta(values, n):
    values = delta(values, n-1) if n > 1 else iter(values)
    a = next(values)
    for b in values:
        yield b - a
        a = b
```

If you don't understand my solution, spend some time studying generators and recursion.

As a comment notes, you don't have to use these solutions. But they are the obvious way to do it, and probably what they're looking for.

Comment: Doesn't "need" generators. Other iterators work as well. Doesn't "need" recursion, either, I'd say, although that's a broad term, so maybe one could argue that however non-recursive I write it, it's still some kind of recursion.

Comment: I agree with the edit :-). And yes, a recursive generator seems simplest and seems to be what the problem writer had in mind, judging by the tags and discussion [at code wars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/6040b781e50db7000ab35125/python).